# How can I see typedef struct component with gdb?

Tags: c, struct, gdb, typedef

I wanna see the typedef struct component with gdb, I get "Attempt to dereference a generic pointer." error. I do not have this problem with struct but I do not want to change the whole code, I am sure there is a way for that. I printed the simple code for that (with petsc) to express the problem more:

```
int main(int argc,char **args)
{

typedef struct{
  PetscReal x;
  PetscReal y;
} Cmpnts;
Cmpnts *vec;
vec = malloc(3 * sizeof (*vec));
PetscInitialize(&argc,&args,(char *)0,help);
 vec[0].x=1.; vec[0].y=2.;
 vec[1].x=1.; vec[1].y=2.;
 vec[2].x=1.; vec[2].y=2.;
 PetscFinalize();
 return 0;
}
```

gdb

```
p vec[0]
```

"Attempt to dereference a generic pointer."

Comment: It works for me: `(gdb) p vec[0]

$1 = {x = 1, y = 2}`

Comment: @user3417696 : Can you add more information - gdb version, the complete stack, where you are trying to get the output in stack etc.